# Convert dataset to xml string with nested repeated xml vice versa

Tags: c#, xml, nested, dataset

I'm trying to convert the dataset with 2 datatables into xml string with nested repeated xml like below example.

Any advice if you have experienced before?

Example:

```
<Items>
  <Code>A001</Code>
  <Qty>3</Qty>
  <SerialNoList>
    <SerialNo>S01</SerialNo>
    <SerialNo>S02</SerialNo>    
    <SerialNo>S03</SerialNo>
  </SerialNoList>
</Items>
```

I have tried with DataRelation for converting dataset to xml but only can get the below format.

```
<Items>
  <Code>A001</Code>
  <Qty>3</Qty>
  <SerialNoList>
    <SerialNo>S01</SerialNo>
  </SerialNoList>
  <SerialNoList>
    <SerialNo>S02</SerialNo>    
  </SerialNoList>
  <SerialNoList>
    <SerialNo>S03</SerialNo>
  </SerialNoList>
</Items>
```

Code:

```
    data.Tables[0].TableName = "Items";
    data.Tables[1].TableName = "SerialNoList";

    DataRelation dataRelation = data.Relations.Add("SerialNo", 
    data.Tables[0].Columns["Code"], data.Tables[1].Columns["Code"]);

    dataRelation.Nested = true;
    data.Tables[1].Columns["Code"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;

    string xmlString = data.GetXml();
```

Data :

```
1st DataTable (Items)
Code     Qty
A001     3

2nd DataTable (SerialNoList)
Code     SerialNo
A001     S01
A001     S02
A001     S03
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, you seem like you have a good question but forgot the code (happens to the best of us), I recommend you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55358502/edit) your question and add your Code for the Classes you're trying to serialize and also the code for how you're trying to serialize them

Comment: The xml samples you posted are not consistent with two tables in a DataSet.  It looks like you are trying to create a know xml format from a DataSet which cannot be done using the DataSet WriteXml method.  The Write Xml method is only designed to handle a limited number of xml descendants.The DateSet name is the first level xml tagThe second level xml tags are the table names.The 3rd level xml tags are the columns in each table.The 4th level tags are the row data.  Once you get more than 4 levels the xml produced is unusable because the data becomes fragmented and cannot be put back together..

Comment: @MindSwipe I have added sample code and data. Appreciate your prompt comment.

Comment: @jdweng do you have any idea how I can achieve this except using dataset writexml or getxml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following using Xml Linq:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication106
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("Code_Serial_No");
            DataTable dtCode = new DataTable("Code");
            ds.Tables.Add(dtCode);

            dtCode.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
            dtCode.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));

            dtCode.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A001", 3});

            DataTable dtSerialNo = new DataTable("Serial_No");
            ds.Tables.Add(dtSerialNo);

            dtSerialNo.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
            dtSerialNo.Columns.Add("SerialNo", typeof(string));

            dtSerialNo.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A001", "S01" });
            dtSerialNo.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A001", "S02" });
            dtSerialNo.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A001", "S03" });

            string xml = "<Items></Items>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement items = doc.Root;

            items.Add(new XElement("Code", ds.Tables["Code"].Rows[0]["Code"]));
            items.Add(new XElement("Qty", ds.Tables["Code"].Rows[0]["Qty"]));

            XElement list = new XElement("SerialNoList");
            items.Add(list);

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Serial_No"].AsEnumerable())
            {
                list.Add(new XElement("SerialNo", row.Field<string>("SerialNo")));
            }

            doc.Save(FILENAME);


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need to work with multiple items

```
    //dataSet is filled with data
    string xml = "";
    foreach (DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables["Items"].Rows)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Detail></Detail>");
        XElement items = doc.Root;

        items.Add(new XElement("Code", dr["Code"]));
        items.Add(new XElement("Qty", dr["Qty"]));

        XElement list = new XElement("SerialNoList");
        items.Add(list);

        foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables["SerialNoList"].Select("Code = '" + dr["Code"] + "'"))
        {
            list.Add(new XElement("SerialNo", row["SerialNo"]));
        }

        xml += doc.ToString();
    }
```